# Send commands to another Batch with User Input

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Batch that its role is list some files in some specific folder and after that it lists the files, it waits for user input. My problem is that I like to automize this process without modify the original batch, in other words send the command to the batch that is waiting using another batch with a minute loop. Searching in some other topics I've found some people sugesting the use of "pipe" to send the commands (Ex: echo STOP | test.bat) but it doesn't work because my batch is waiting for user input. Do you have some ideia to send commands in the time that batch waits for user input?

```
Example:

Files stopped in download folder:

test.txt

COMMAND:
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question as well, but maybe this is a direction to look for : you can use the CHOICE command as a combined sleep and wait for input functionality. Ex., choice /t 60

Comment: I can't change the original batch, I just want to send the command that batch is waiting...The bacth after listing the files on the first run, it waits for user input, can be 2 commands, "list" or "exit", I want to send these commands using CMD or another batch

Comment: Show the code you have already

Answer (score 0):

Save commands into the INPUT.TXT, then redirect it to the batch like this:

```
    type INPUT.TXT | mybatch.bat
or
    mybatch.bat < INPUT.TXT
```

```
Here is the working example:
```

```
    :: TEST.BAT
    CHOICE /C:YN /M "Do you have another CD? Y N"
    @if %errorlevel% == 2 ECHO pressed N
    @if %errorlevel% == 1 ECHO pressed Y

    CHOICE /C:YN /M "Do you have another CD? Y N"
    @if %errorlevel% == 2 ECHO pressed N
    @if %errorlevel% == 1 ECHO pressed Y
```

```
    :: INPUT.TXT
    Y
    N
```

```
    C:\temp>type INPUT.TXT | TEST.BAT

    C:\temp>CHOICE /C:YN /M "Do you have another CD? Y N"
    Do you have another CD? Y N [Y,N]?Y
    pressed Y

    C:\temp>CHOICE /C:YN /M "Do you have another CD? Y N"
    Do you have another CD? Y N [Y,N]?N
    pressed N

    C:\temp>
```